# Error:SingleFieldIdentity

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Can anybody please tell me the cause of this error:--

An object of class "entity.pendingRequest" uses SingleFieldIdentity using the field "empId" yet this field has not had its value set! Either set the field manually, or set a value-strategy for that field.

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it, you've designated `empId` as your primary key, but haven't supplied a value, or told it how to generate one, before attempting to store a recored.